# Can I consume data from SharePoint 2013 with a web service executed from an ASP.Net page?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services, sharepoint

So there are actually two web services involved,
1) SP 2013 executing a web service which reaches out to data from a SQL Server DB
2) ASP.Net page executing a web service that reaches out to data from SP2013 (like items in a list).

1 seems feasible I think because SP2013 authenticates users at the AD level and the service would execute as the user. If the DB allows read access to all there should be no issue, right?

2 I'm not sure about. Would the service be executed as something like "ASPNET USER" or "NETWORK SERVICE" or something that's not the user account? Meaning the service would get access denied because "ASPNET USER" doesn't have access to the SP site/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can consume data from SharePoint 2013 in your ASP.Net application or in any other platform. But instead of creating a new web service to make it (avoid querying the SharePoint SQL Server database directly), you could use the native SharePoint web services.

To consume data in lists, libraries, etc from your portal you can use the lists.asmx web service with the GetListItems method.

When you call the GetListItems method, you can identify the user credentials:

```
myListsService.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user",
                                                    "password",
                                                    "domain");
```

See this link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

How to return List Items: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms429658(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms429658%28v=office.14%29.aspx)